Subgradient of the matrix norm
When I want to obtain statistical properties of the matrix-variate lasso method, for example,
$$
\hat{X}=\underset{X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}{\arg \min}\mathcal{L}\left(X\right)+\lambda_n \|X\|_1,
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the loss function and $\|X\|_1=\sum_{i,j}|X_{ij}|$, I always focus on the KKT condition from its directional derivative. Thus, I have that
$$
\mathcal{L}^{\prime}\left(\hat{X}\right)+\lambda_n Z,
$$
where $Z\in \partial\|\hat{X}\|_1$ and $\|Z\|_{\max}=\underset{i,j}{\max}|Z_{ij}|\le 1$.
Could we bound the spectral norm of $Z$? I learned that if $Z$ is the subgradient of the nuclear norm, the spectral norm of $Z$ is smaller than 1. Does the element-wise 1 norm have a similar property?

If you don't get an answer here, you could try at https://math.stackexchange.com/  or we can migrate it there for you. Some related Qs there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105044/about-subgradient-of-matrix-norm, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527810/derivation-of-subgradient-of-a-matrixs-nuclear-norm,
